# Import Java classes once for all package

Tags: java, class, import, package, project-structure

Let's say, I have the following structure:

- src.main.java

  - first

    - one.java
    - two.java
    - three.java
  - second

    - alpha.java
    - beta.java
    - gamma.java

I want all classes from `first` package to be imported in all classes in my `second` package.

Now I'm just specifying for every class in `second` package:

```
import first.*;
```

Can I import once for **all** classes in package?

Comment: I cannot see what you actually want to do. Why would you want to get rid of the wildcard import at the beginning of each of the classes of your second package?

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez The question wasn't why. :) I've asked if it is possible. And I've already received answers, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it cannot be done.

I don't see why this is such a hardship.

A better solution would be to use an IDE that can add the imports as you need them.

I'd also recommend spelling each one out individually rather than using the star notation, even if you need to import all of them.  It documents your intent better, and that IDE can make it transparent to you.

Answer (score 2):

No, **you can't do that** in Java.

One thing that you might think of doing is moving classes from `second` package to `first` so you won't need the imports. But I understand that that is not always possible/desirable.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes it may help. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I import once for all classes in package?

No you can't.  Imports only apply to the <strike>class</strike> *source file* in which they are declared.

> Maybe I can create some superclass with import statements and then extend it every time?

That will only work if the code in the subclasses does not mention the names of the external types at all ... which is rarely possible.

As I said imports only apply to the <strike>class</strike> *source file* in which they are declared.

---

Actually, the `import` was deliberately designed to work this way.  The idea is to allow you to easily figure out what class a classname refers to.  (It works best if you don't use star imports ...)

Comment: Maybe I can create some `superclass` with import statements and then `extend` it every time?

Comment: Sorry, that's just ridiculous.  Do the imports and get over it.

Comment: @duffymo No need to apologize. :) I'm just asking. I understand that extending in this manner is very undesirable.

Comment: *Imports only apply to the **sourcefile** in which they are declared.* ;)