# Is it possible to import several packages at once in Java?

Tags: java, java-package

I would like for example to do the following:

```
import packageA.*, packageB.*;
```

but the above notation does not work. Is it possible to do this somehow in Java, or do I always have to type:

```
import packageA.*;
import packageB.*;
```

?

Comment: Which editor you used?

Comment: With any decent IDE, you never have to type any import statement. You just use the class you want, hit ctrl-space, and the IDE adds the import for you. Importing a whole package is bad practice. Prefer class imports.

Comment: In Eclipse you just have to use CTRL+SHIFT+O. will import and remove unused import also.

Comment: I can't recall why, it is better to use full name rather than importing all of classes at once by using (*). So it is better to use like this: import packageA.util.MyClass1;  import packageA.util.MyClass2; import packageB.gui.GuiClass1; import packageB.gui.GuiClass2;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import Java classes once for all package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933859/import-java-classes-once-for-all-package)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible in Java to perform two imports with one import statement.
So yes, you always have to do

```
import packageA.*;
import packageB.*;
```

You can find out more about the syntax of `import` statement in the [Java Language Specification section 7.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5)

There are four different types of `import` declarations but none of them can import more than one thing per import statement:

```
ImportDeclaration:
    SingleTypeImportDeclaration
    TypeImportOnDemandDeclaration   
    SingleStaticImportDeclaration   
    StaticImportOnDemandDeclaration
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot be done.

I don't see why this is such a hardship.

A better solution would be to use an IDE that can add the imports as you need them.

I'd also recommend spelling each one out individually rather than using the star notation, even if you need to import all of them. It documents your intent better, and that IDE can make it transparent to you.